# Sitecore How to get the value inside the field 'Media' of a Media Item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

**Update 2:** 
I am still fighting to get the Icon save on the server.

Here what I am doing:

```cs
Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(imageId);
var imageIconUrl = Sitecore.Resources.Images.GetThemedImageSource(item.Appearance.Icon, ImageDimension.id32x32);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(imageIconUrl))
{
  // download the icon from the url 
  var iconFullPath = "e:\\pngIcons\\excelIcon.png"; 
  var webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
  var downloadPath = "http://serverName/" + imageIconUrl;
  webClient.DownloadFile(downloadPath, iconFullPath);
}
```

The variable `downloadPath` contains following string:

```
http://serverName/sitecore/shell/themes/standard/~/media/E503BA48C89B422D8400393F1C7086A7.ashx?h=32&thn=1&w=32&db=master
```

At the end what I can see is a png file but there is nothing in it. I also copy the string I get in variable `downloadPath` and pasted it in browser and I can see the Icon as follow:

[image]

**Please let me know what I am doing wrong.** Or How I can save the Icon. Thanks!!

**Original Question:**

The sitecore media item has a field "`Media`". I am talking about this:

[image]

I want to access this field. And the reason is:

If I access it with e.g. `item.GetMediaStream()` then I will get the complete file. I just want to save this little icon some how on the server. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 6):

To get the icon/thumbnail you can use

```
var icon = Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaManager.GetThumbnailUrl(mediaItem);
```

To get the url of the thumbnail.

If you want the stream of the thumbnail you need to use the `MediaData` object. Like this:

```
var mediaItem = new MediaItem(item)
var mediaData = new MediaData(mediaItem);
var iconStream = mediaData.GetThumbnailStream();
if (iconStream.Length < 0) 
{
    // The stream is empty, its probably a file that Sitecore can't 
    // generate a thumbnail for. Just use the Icon
    var icon = item.Appearance.Icon;
}
```

This will get the icon or thumbnail of the actual media blob that is attached to the media item. If you just want the icon of the Sitecore item, then use Martins method.

If the stream is empty, then Sitecore can't generate a thumbnail for it, so you can just use the icon file for the media item template. `item.Appearance.Icon`

Comment: But how will I save `iconStream` in above case on Server. I mean to say with `System.IO` stream I can use `.CopyTo(path)` and then save the stream.

Comment: Yes, I got it with `var stream = iconStream.Stream;`

Comment: Sorry to bother you but if the file is not an Image file then saving a file with this method is not successful. The file size is 0 KB. E.g In an Excel file.

Comment: I think this is because the file you have doesn't have a generated thumbnail and so Sitecore will just use the Icon associated with the media type, in this case an Excel file.  So you can just use the items icon property. I have updated the answer to reflect this. Also Martins answer will work if the stream is empty.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, but I am still struggling to find out how to Download the stream from an Icon. If you know then please let me know how I can save this `var icon = item.Appearance.Icon;` as a Image on server.

Comment: `item.Apperance.Icon` gives you the path to the Icon file that is already stored on disk. You can use `Server.MapPath` to get at that file, or you could use a `WebRequest` using the icon path to download the image in the response and at that point save it to disk if the `Server.MapPath` method doesn't find the icon.

Answer (score 0):

**Appearance** section (of **Standard Template**) has a field called `Icon` - this is where you can modify icon for the item. There is also a field called `Thumbnail` - your excel icon is sitting there

You can access the field programmatically, just mind that it starts with two underscores: `__Icon`:

```cs
var iconField = item.Fields["__Icon"];
var thumbnailField = item.Fields["__Thumbnail"];
```

**Update:** As you asked, below is the code that saves either of fields into the file on a drive. I have tested the code and confirm successfully stores icon from thumbnail field into the file:

```cs
string mediaItemPath = "/sitecore/media library/Files/ExcelFile";
string mediaFiedlName = "Thumbnail"; // also can be "__Icon"

var item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(mediaItemPath);

var iconField = item.Fields[mediaFiedlName];
if (iconField.HasBlobStream)
{
  var thumb = (ImageField)iconField;

  var bl = ((MediaItem)thumb.MediaItem).InnerItem.Fields["blob"];
  Stream stream = bl.GetBlobStream();

  byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
  using (FileStream fs = File.Create("D:\\you_file_name.ico")) // change your path
  {
    int length;
    do
    {
      length = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      fs.Write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    while (length > 0);

    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
  }
}
```

**Update 2:** If that does not help then I would advise to look around the way how that icon gets generated on Media field in Sitecore. In the worst case you may do the following - right click that icon and see its url. You will have something similar to what I assign to variable below:

```cs
string url = "http://test81/sitecore/shell/Applications/-/media/B4F61650CBE84EE396649602C0C48E1B.ashx?bc=White&db=master&h=128&la=en&mw=640&thn=1&vs=1&ts=b8046903-ae57-4f9d-9dd5-b626ee5eee90";
```

Of course your URL should have your hostname and media prefix and the rest of parameters. Then use Webclient with that modified URL:

```cs
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(url, "e:\\you_file_name.ico");
```

Not ideal, but may work. Note, that the code above should work in a context of already logged user, so you need to authorise you Webclient prior that (many articles on S.O. how to do that).

Please reply if that approach has worked for you (*I've spent decent time writing and testing that code in debugger, so would want to know whether that helped*)

Comment: How Can I save the `var icon` on the server as an image file. Thanks!

Comment: Just updated my answer with the code to save icon to disk via stream

Comment: `var field = item.Fields["__Icon"]` is not a blob field. I have checked in the debugger `IsBlobField` has value `false` and also `HasBlobStream` is also `false`.

Comment: I have updated my answer again, please test the updated code that worked out well for me, anв let me know if that worked

Comment: Thanks. But `iconField.HasBlobStream` is always false. I tried with ``__Icon` and `__Thumbnail`. But Its always false. I tried with Image file even then its false. I mean jpg file in Media Items.

Comment: If nothing works for you then the only I think you can do is to look around how that icon is generated. I would probably debug that Sitecore code that generates preview icon and reworked it as require. If not then you may look Update 2 from my answer as the last resort.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried this also but its not working. Please see my updated question. Thanks.